# How to deploy the extension of Firebug Lite?

Tags: deployment, firebug-lite

On the [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) website there is information on how to write an extension for Firebug Lite, but it doesn't say how to deploy that extension.

I read that deploying an extension for Firebug is like installing a plugin in Firefox. Is it gonna be the same for an extension of Firebug Lite?

Comment: Note that there is nobody working on Firebug Lite anymore as [mentioned by Honza in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebug/3RTAoPgQA-k/S5bBkgmvZeQJ). You may want to write your extension for the Firefox DevTools instead. [FireQuery](https://github.com/firebug/firequery) is an example for how to do that and the [Firebug SDK](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.sdk) helps by providing related APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend Firebug Lite by simply including your script on the page as shown on the Firebug Lite website:

```
Firebug.extend(function(FBL) { with (FBL) {
// ***********************************************************************

function PluginPanel(){};

PluginPanel.prototype = extend(Firebug.Panel,
{
    name: "Plugin",
    title: "Plugin",

    initialize: function(){
        Firebug.Panel.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        this.panelNode.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    }
});

Firebug.registerPanel(PluginPanel);

// ***********************************************************************
}});
```

To include your extension the code needs to be executed after Firebug Lite is loaded. E.g. this can be done by saving the code above into a file and include it via a `<script>` tag after including Firebug Lite:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-firebug-lite-extension.js"></script>
```